# Can a barbarian keep raging if she shoves an enemy on her turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, barbarian, rage

A barbarian has to stop raging if their turn ends and they haven't **attacked a hostile creature since their last turn** or taken damage since their last turn. (PHB 48)

**Can I shove an enemy on my turn (without dealing or taking damage) to maintain my Rage?**

Since [shoving](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) is described as a "special melee attack" (PHB 195), my instinct is that a shove should work to maintain Rage, but it seems unclear to me.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes, barbarians can shove or grapple enemies to continue raging.

The description of the barbarian's [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage) feature says:

> Your rage lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or **if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then**. You can also end your rage on your turn as a bonus action.

To keep your rage from ending early, you have to either attack a hostile creature or take damage, between the end of your last turn and the end of your current turn.

As you point out, [shoves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) are described as a "special melee attack":

> Using the Attack action, you can make a **special melee attack** to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) is described the same way:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a **special melee attack**, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

Note that Rage doesn't say the attack has to "hit" - something that can only happen with attack rolls - which means it doesn't require attack rolls, so these special melee attacks are a valid way of attacking in order to keep raging.

---

[Rules designer Jeremy Crawford unofficially confirms this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/596096614042771456), in response to some confusion over grapples/shoves being attacks but not involving attack rolls:

> *Does a barbarian keep his rage if he uses his action to grapple if grappling is not an attack?*
>
> **The grapple option in the Player's Handbook is an attack, but it uses an ability check in place of an attack roll.**

Here he reiterates what's already stated in the rules: grapples and shoves are attacks, so attempting to grapple or shove a hostile creature does allow you to continue your Rage.